# Finding most recent datetime in list before a given datetime

Tags: python, datetime, numpy, pandas, timestamp

I have a two lists of datetimes in `np.datetime64` format. (Not necessary - could be unix timestamp or `datetime.datetime`)

As I iterate through the dense list (`times_dense`), I want to get the time from `times_sparse` closest to but less than the time from `times_dense`. I'm terrible at `datetime` so I just threw this together.

```
most_recent_time = None

for time_d in times_dense:
    for time_s in times_sparse:
        # time_d is after time_s and time_s is after most_recent_time
        if(time_d >= time_s and time_s > most_recent_time):
            most_recent_time = time_s

return most_recent_time
```

Is there an easy way to do this? Will my method even work? It is clunky and has a large running time. What's the best way to solve this?

**PS.** I have these originally in a pandas dataframe but took them out because I couldn't find a solution within the dataframe. If this can work with pandas, that would be even better.

Comment: What exactly are `times_dense` and `times_sparse`?  Python lists, numpy arrays, scipy sparse matrix, or some iterable of your own making?

Comment: Both are np arrays now. But they could be lists or in a pandas dataframe.

Comment: What is the importance of most_recent_time? Also, when you say you want the closest time in time_sparse to time_dense, are you targeting a particular given element in time_dense, or do you wish to find a pair of time elements, one in time_sparse and the other in time_dense, which have a minimum distance compared to other possible pairs?

Comment: `most_recent_time` just looks like a temporary value used to find the maximum (or minimum) iteratively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a time comparison along the lines that you describe.  For now I'm focusing on recreating your situation, not making it optimal

Make two arrays of dates:

```
In [434]: t1=np.array(np.random.randint(100,size=(10,)),dtype='datetime64[D]')

In [435]: t2=np.array(np.random.randint(100,size=(10,)),dtype='datetime64[D]')

In [436]: t1
Out[436]: 
array(['1970-02-25', '1970-01-31', '1970-01-04', '1970-03-17',
       '1970-03-17', '1970-01-02', '1970-02-09', '1970-04-05',
       '1970-02-22', '1970-03-08'], dtype='datetime64[D]')

In [437]: t2
Out[437]: 
array(['1970-01-16', '1970-02-24', '1970-02-28', '1970-01-21',
       '1970-03-08', '1970-03-22', '1970-02-02', '1970-02-12',
       '1970-02-24', '1970-02-06'], dtype='datetime64[D]')
```

A start date:

```
In [438]: recent=np.datetime64(0,'D')

In [439]: recent
Out[439]: numpy.datetime64('1970-01-01')
```

your iterations:

```
In [440]: for td in t1:
    for ts in t2:
        if (td>=ts) and (ts>recent):
            recent=ts
   .....:             

In [441]: recent
Out[441]: numpy.datetime64('1970-03-22')
```

`np.datetime64` can handle comparisons (and arithmetic) just fine.

`np.array` with `np.datetime64` values can be used in the same ways arrays with integer values

(for a different `t2`):

```
In [458]: t2.max()
Out[458]: numpy.datetime64('1970-04-05')

In [459]: t2[np.argmax(t1>=t2[:,None],axis=0)]
Out[459]: 
array(['1970-02-08', '1970-03-07', '1970-03-07', '1970-03-07',
       '1970-03-07', '1970-03-07', '1970-02-08', '1970-03-07',
       '1970-02-08', '1970-03-07'], dtype='datetime64[D]')
```

An expression like this last one probably could reproduce your iteration - but it needs tweaking.